# Creating n by n Array of Instances with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, object, numpy

I'm trying to create a n by n array of objects with NumPy and here are my problems: Let's assume the dimension of the array are set to `m=n=3`. To each element of I would like to assign an instance of my class `Vector`, which is a n-dimensional vector type.

In my first attempt I tried to assign a 2-dim. vector in the following way:

```
    array_size = 4
    np.array([ 
          [ Vector(1,2) for j in xrange(array_size) ] 
          for i in xrange(array_size) ], dtype=object)
```

Instead of an array of `Vector` instances Python returns:

```
[[[1 2]
  [1 2]
  [1 2]]

 [[1 2]
  [1 2]
  [1 2]]

 [[1 2]
  [1 2]
  [1 2]]]
```

The above is an array of shape `(3, 3, 2)`, not of `(2, 2)`. Numpy converted the `Vector`instances to a third array dimension. This is not what I wanted, so I tried another thing:

I first defined an empty object array and then assigned the instances to it:

```
    array_size=3
    mx = np.empty([array_size, array_size], dtype=object).astype(list)

    for i in xrange(array_size):
        for j in xrange(array_size):
            mx[i][j] = Vector(1,2)
```

The funny thing about it is that I have to cast the array to a list. Then it works pretty well and returns exactly what I need:

```
[[< Vector: [1, 2] > < Vector: [1, 2] > < Vector: [1, 2] >]  
 [< Vector: [1, 2] > < Vector: [1, 2] > < Vector: [1, 2] >]  
 [< Vector: [1, 2] > < Vector: [1, 2] > < Vector: [1, 2] >]]
```

It is then possible to cast the list back to an array. So, the array can(!) hold objects in the way I want it to. But there seems to be no straightforward way to assign the instances. And, isn't there a more pythonic to do it? I really want to get rid of this nested loop.

I also tried out `np.nditer`:

```
    array_size=3
    mx = np.empty([array_size, array_size], dtype=object)

    for i in np.nditer(mx, flags=["refs_ok"], op_flags=["writeonly"]):
        i[...] = Vector(1, 2)
```

Instead of an array, this one returns an error:

> ValueError: assignment to 0-d array

which I do not understand.

Does anybody have a good solution concerning the nested loop? An explanation of the value error would also be welcome.

Comment: So the big question is why do have your own `Vector` class? The (num)Pythonic way is to use the numpy array class for everything (as the `array` constructor returns in your example code), reshaping and slicing as necessary.

Comment: `Vector` inherits from `np.ndarray` and provides some simplifications and extensions of the vector algebraic functionality. So, the big question is: "Why doesn't it work even if I use plain `ndarray` instead of `Vectors`?"

Comment: I think the first attempt likely fails because Vector is a ndarray, so your instances will have the array interface (see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html ).  Perhaps change your Vector class to have an ndarray attribute instead of being an ndarray subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop should work if you *don't* cast to a list, and if you do the assignment like:

```
        mx[i,j] = Vector(1,2)
```

---

In your first attempt, `np.array` is just doing its job.  It sees a nested collection of data that can be converted to a 3-D array, so it does so.

To get a 2-D array of objects, you can change this:

```
a = np.array(<nested list of Vectors>, dtype=object)  # Doesn't work as desired.
```

to this:

```
vectors = <nested list of Vectors>
a = np.empty(<desired shape>, dtype=object)
a[...] = vectors
```

Here's a concrete example:

I don't have your `Vector` class, so I'll just use numpy arrays as the objects that I want in the array of objects.

Here's the data that I want to put into an array of objects. It is a nested list of numpy arrays, each with two elements:

```
In [26]: vectors = [[np.array([10*j + k, 10*j + k + 1]) for k in range(3)] for j in range(3)]

In [27]: vectors
Out[27]: 
[[array([0, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([2, 3])],
 [array([10, 11]), array([11, 12]), array([12, 13])],
 [array([20, 21]), array([21, 22]), array([22, 23])]]
```

You could change `np.array([10*j + k, 10*j + k + 1])` to `Vector(10*j + k, 10*j + k + 1)` to try this with your `Vector` class.

`a` is the array of objects that I'm creating:

```
In [28]: a = np.empty((3, 3), dtype=object)
```

Assign the vectors to `a` like this:

```
In [29]: a[...] = vectors   # or `a[:,:] = vectors` 

In [30]: a
Out[30]: 
array([[array([0, 1]), array([1, 2]), array([2, 3])],
       [array([10, 11]), array([11, 12]), array([12, 13])],
       [array([20, 21]), array([21, 22]), array([22, 23])]], dtype=object)

In [31]: a.shape
Out[31]: (3, 3)
```

Comment: Good answer. Thank you, I tried this out and it worked. For some reason my nested for loop is about 12 % faster than your code.(1000 x 1000 array of 3d vectors) Seems like I have to live with the loops ;-)